# Visual Basic raising event on Windows Forms Dialog and handling on Main Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, dialog

I've got a dialog window (called Dialog1) and my main form, (called Form1).

How can I respond to an event on Dialog1 from Form1 in Windows forms? Should I have made Dialog1 another form and instantiated it using the `WithEvents` keyword?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the **"event"** in question?  Does something need to occur while Dialog1 is **still open**?...or after it has been closed by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have this declaration in your `Form1`:

```
Private WithEvents dialog As Dialog1
```

Then set its reference when the form loads (you can't have a `WithEvents` declaration that's *also* assigning a reference):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set dialog = New Dialog1
End Sub
```

And now you can handle any event exposed by the `Dialog1` class/form - including your custom ones - just select `dialog` from the left-hand dropdown at the top of the code pane in the IDE, and select the event to handle from the right-hand dropdown.

Or just type the handler by hand:

```
Private Sub dialog_Activate()
    '"Activate" event handler for dialog
End Sub

Private sub dialog_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    '"QueryClose" event handler for dialog
End Sub
```

Also, do yourself a favor, and *name things*. "Dialog1" and "Form1" are awful names.